# How does tannin level and acidity affect cider taste/style?

Tags: cider, ph

As per the title really... if you had tannin level on one axis of a graph and pH on another, how would the cider vary across this 'spectrum'? More acidic I can imagine will taste... more acidic ;) But I'm wondering how a low/none amount of tannin would taste, or a very non-acidic must. Would you get something sweet, or just bland and insipid?

Comment: "sweet or just bland" depends on other factors, like yeast attenuation level, for example. All we can really say is that more tannins means more astringent batch, more acids mean more acidic, and these tastes are pretty independent, and independent from apparent sweetness. "sweet and sour chicken" is one of the most common examples of these two together.

Comment: Level of tannins can also affect the body/mouth feel and will affect how the cider ages. Cider apples tend to have far higher levels of tannins in the skins compared to eating apples.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of links to help you with this:

Tannins:

http://www.cider.org.uk/tannin.htm

Acids:

http://www.cider.org.uk/phandacid.htm

http://www.cider.org.uk/tlctext.htm

From what I have been reading around this, you need some acidity, some sweetness and some tannins, too little of one makes an unbalanced cider. Say acidic and sweet with no tannins would be thin and lacking body.

Too much acid and tannin with no sugar would be harsh and dry.

Too much tannin and sugar would lack the fruity essence of cider.

A dry west country UK cider would be low in sugar with higher tannins and acidity, where as a sweet north french cider would be lower in tannins and much higher in residual or added sugars.